# Linear Algebra: Two independent vectors in a 3 space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to learn linear algebra through Strang's book.

It says that all linear combinations of two independent vectors say, $(0, 0, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 0)$ will geometrically form a **plane** in a $3$-d space.

Aren't all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ available to a linear combination of these vectors if we choose the right scaling constants?

*I went through a few questions like this, but did not get the concept clearly.*

Comment: How would you write $(1,0,0)$?

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is, among other properties, the minimum number of vectors necessary to express every vector as a linear combination thereof. So two vectors cannot suffice to write every vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as linear combination of them.

Comment: @MikeMiller You are absolutely right. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot.